# Why is my array being recognized as a double?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

On the line where I call getDistance(points[i], points[j]) I am getting error asking my to change my getDistance method parameters to doubles instead of arrays, though I thought I was passing an array to the method due to how multidimensional arrays work.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[][] points = {
        {1.0, 2.0, 3.0},
        {0.0, 0.0, 2.0},
        {1.0, 1.5, 4.0},
        {3.0, 2.0, 1.0}
    };

    for(int i=0; i<points.length; i++){
        for(int j=1; j<points[0].length; j++){
            getDistance(points[i], points[j]);
        }
    }

}

public double getDistance(Array points1[], Array points2[]){
    double x1 = Array.getDouble(points1, 0);
    double x2 = Array.getDouble(points2, 0);
    double y1 = Array.getDouble(points1, 1);
    double y2 = Array.getDouble(points2, 1);
    double z1 = Array.getDouble(points1, 2);
    double z2 = Array.getDouble(points2, 2);

    double distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x1 - x2, 2) +(Math.pow(y1 - y2, 2) + 
                        (Math.pow(z1 - z2, 2))));
    return distance;

}
```

Comment: What is `Array` in `public double getDistance(Array points1[], Array points2[])`?

Comment: what do you mean what is array in it? I was stating that i was passing 2 arrays into the method, and those arrays are passed as points[i] and points[j] because points is a multidimensional array, so as far as I know, points[i] should pass in points[0][0 through 2]

Comment: The type of `points[i]` isn't `Array[]`. It's `double[]` (i.e. a `double` array).

Comment: Your method accepts array of some type named `Array`, but you are passing `double` array. Java doesn't have `Array` type which could be used to store any array (and even if it had then in this case you would need to pass multiple dimension array). There is `java.lang.reflect.Array` type but it is utility class which allows us to operate on arrays using reflection, not to store array references. Hence my question. There would probably be more following questions later but to ask them I would like to know more about what you used in your code and why you think it should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your method `getDistance` defines the two parameters as type `Array` where as where you call it the type is `double[]` which is not the same.

Rewrite your `getDistance` as follows;

```
public double getDistance(double[] points1, double[] points2){
    double x1 = points1[0];
    double x2 = points2[0];
    double y1 = points1[1];
    double y2 = points2[1];
    double z1 = points1[2];
    double z2 = points2[2];

    double distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x1 - x2, 2) +(Math.pow(y1 - y2, 2) + 
                        (Math.pow(z1 - z2, 2))));
    return distance;
}
```

Comment: Been a while since i visited this content. doing make up work right now and just face palmed... dunno how i goofed that up. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Your method should declare an array the same as you did in your main.

Now:
Instead of `public double getDistance(Array points1[], Array points2[])`

Should be:
`public double getDistance(double points1[], double points2[])`

Comment: You could improve your answer by supplying a more extensive code example.